# How do I extract values from an array based on a common value?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set create pareto graphs based on a dataset from excel. The dataset has three columns "Comment", "part", and "number". The values in comment and number repeat as they are general while the part is independent. As such, I need to group them based on the part.

I've been able to create two pareto graphs. By getting the unique part numbers and counting the number of occurrences of unique comments, I have been able to create a plot of number of comments (y-axis) and part (x-axis). Now the part I've been struggling with is plotting the number of comments (y-axis) by the number (x- axis) for a specified part.

```
Data = readtable('Example_Dataset.xlsx')
Data = Data{:,:}
part = Data(:,2) %Gets part
number = Data(:,3) %Gets number
comments = Data(:,1) %gets comment

Unique_Part= unique(part,'stable')
b = cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(part,x)),Unique_Part,'un',0)
Unique_number = unique(number,'stable')
c = cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(number,x)),Unique_number,'un',0)
Unique_comments = unique(comments,'stable')
comment_type =cell2mat(Unique_comments)
comments_parts = cell2mat(b)
comments_number = cell2mat(c)

figure
pareto(comments_parts,Unique_part)

figure
pareto(comments_number,Unique_number)
```

A simplified dataset is shown here. It should be noted that they are not equal sizes, some repeat only once others repeat numberous times. And sometimes the part is not numeric.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5tGM.jpg

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Why not post the editable version of the simplified dataset so that we can run on our computer?

Comment: The error I am getting is that pareto(comments_number,Unique_number) is wrong. It makes sense but its not what I want. Since the numbers and comments repeat for different parts, the number of occurrences is too high. What i need is a way to say i only want the numbers by the comments for all parts that are labeled "1". I've tried using ismember(part,1) but this gives me a logical. I'm still new to Matlab so I may be missing something.